# Creating New Odoo Instance From Existing Odoo Database

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I'm trying to create a new Odoo instances using data that exists in the postgres database of an already running instance.

I'm planning on using an SQL dump from the existing DB or setting a template DB in odoo configurations.

The problem is that I get an internal server error when odoo starts because the database contains information on installed modules, but the new instance would not have those modules installed.

What's a good way to get around this?
Would it be possible to remove that data from the database or sql dump file beforehand and would that make the issue go away?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up running Odoo database with same version, then make sure you have same addons / module version, postgres version and mentioned addons-path in same sequence as in production/running system. Like addons, custom-addons, oca-addons, link-addons etc

If you are setting up running Odoo database with upper version, then you have to migrate the database and source code.